# Best way to expose an object with read-only properties only

Tags: vb.net, properties, accessor

I can't find an answer to my question so I'm asking a new one.

I have an object where I want to fill it's properties from another class in the same solution. But the object should expose read-only properties only so the outside-caller can't see nor access the setter (cause there is no setter).

What is the best way to fill the internal backing variables from the same solution? I know I could do it in the constructor but I want to be able to set the variables after creating the object.

Sorry for my weird explaination, maybe a bit of code could help.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
Public Class ReadonlyObject

    Protected Friend Sub New()
    End Sub

    'Could use this, but don't want to...
    Protected Friend Sub New(foo As String)
    End Sub

    Friend _foo As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Foo As String
        Get
            Return _foo
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Public Class FillReadonlyObject

    Private Sub DoSomeHeavyWork()
        Dim roObject As New ReadonlyObject

        roObject._foo = "bar"

        'Could use this, but don't want to...want to access properties directly.
        Dim roObject2 As New ReadonlyObject("bar")

    End Sub

End Class
```

With this, the ReadonlyObject's properties are correctly exposed as readonly but I'm afraid it's bad practice.

I've seen implementations like this:

```
Public Class ReadonlyObject

Protected Friend Sub New()
End Sub

Private _foo As String

Public Property Foo As String
    Get
        Return _foo
    End Get
    Friend Set(value As String)
        _foo = value
    End Set
End Property

End Class

Public Class FillReadonlyObject

Private Sub DoSomeHeavyWork()
    Dim roObject As New ReadonlyObject

    roObject.Foo = "bar"
End Sub

End Class
```

This works, but exposes the property with a setter. It's not accessible, but it's visible and I don't want that :)

So maybe it's only a cosmetic thing but I think it's nice to tell the caller (or at least intellisense) the property is strictly read-only.

Thanks, Jan

Comment: The only question that comes to my mind is: *why*? You want to change the value of a property, there are three solutions: a) constructor or any other method takes the property values as parameters, b) property has setter or c) you change the member variable behind the property, in case of which having a property doesn't make sense in the first place.

Comment: So how about a Private setter instead of Friend?

Comment: He then can not set the property from other classes in the project.

Comment: True.  He would need to set it either through a Friend/Public method or through the constructor.

Comment: @Thorsten: "why" is easy to answer: It look's cleaner, I think. Sure, I can do it in the constructor but then I need to know all values while creating the object. This is often not the case. Or I could use friend methods, but that's a bit of overload, ins't it?

Comment: But the whole point about something being *read only* is that it can *not be changed* from the outside. As you want to change your properties from the outside, you either can't make them read only, or you need to implement other methods like the constructor/method approach.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the `Public Get/Friend Set` approach. It's the simplest, it's the cleanest.

Comment: @DominicKexel Agreed.  That is the most obvious way to do it, and it's not entirely clear why that's unacceptable in this situation.

Comment: @StevenDoggart It is acceptable but you could "see" the setter from outside of the assembly. You can't use it, but you can see it. And for me (and maybe for me only), it's not 'nice'. It's like the pretty girl next to you, you can see her, but you can't touch her (at least you shouldn't :))

Comment: What do you mean by you can *see* the setter? If you use just the assembly without the source code, you can not *see* the setter. Only if you have the source code you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explicitly declare the property as read-only, but then still have a way to set it after it is constructed, then all you need to do is create your own setter method rather than using the one automatically created for you but the property.  For instance:

```
Public Class ReadonlyObject
    Protected Friend Sub New()
    End Sub

    Private _foo As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Foo As String
        Get
            Return _foo
        End Get
    End Property

    Friend Sub SetFoo(value As String)
        _foo = value
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class FillReadonlyObject
    Private Sub DoSomeHeavyWork()
        Dim roObject As New ReadonlyObject
        roObject.SetFoo("bar")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Or, you could create two properties, like this:

```
Public Class ReadonlyObject
    Protected Friend Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Foo As String
        Get
            Return HiddenFoo
        End Get
    End Property

    Friend Property HiddenFoo As String
End Class

Public Class FillReadonlyObject
    Private Sub DoSomeHeavyWork()
        Dim roObject As New ReadonlyObject
        roObject.HiddenFoo = "bar"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Sure I could do this, but why not declare the backing variable as friend and access it directly? Is this so bad behaviour?

Comment: @Jan If you do that, then why have the readonly property in the first place if you can just circumvent it?

Comment: @Jan, Good point, but I wouldn't recommend accessing the field directly.  It's best to always use properties if you can.  However, that gave me another idea, which I added to my answer.

Comment: Upvoted for the 1st answer, which is a better solution IMO.  It's exactly the sort of thing you would do in Java, which doesn't have "properties".

Comment: @Douglas Sorry, don't understand what you mean. I can't circumvent the read-only property from outside.

Comment: @Steven Nice idea, but accessing it directly is still easier :) And I need to create a "hidden" property for each read-only property...too much work I think.

Comment: If you have a Readonly property "Foo" and a Friend/Public Property "HiddenFoo", then there is nothing to stop someone from just referring to HiddenFoo directly.  So this brings up the question, why have Foo at all?  The only thing it would accomplish is that it would be read-only from outside of the assembly.

Comment: @Jan, I think what he's saying is that if you made the private `_foo` field a `Friend`, you'd be allowing code outside of that class to directly manipulate the value of the read-only property, which certainly does fly in the face of standard practice and intent.  It might cause people to at least scratch their heads at first when they see it.  That's why I'd recommend the `Friend` being either a method, the constructor, or a second property--so the class is still in control of the value of that read-only property.

Comment: @Douglas HiddenFoo can't be accessed from outside if it's declared as friend.

Comment: @Jan it can be accessed from outside the class.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin I can think of many cases where "the only reason would be to have the property be read-only outside of the assembly" is plenty reason enough.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Good point, but I think that the extra Friend property is just a more "hacked-together" solution than having a Set method.

Comment: @Steven I'm developing a class library so friend declaration is fully ok as long as it's not declared public.

Comment: @Jan, I fail to see how my second example is any harder to implement then what you are describing... It's the exact same number of lines of code...  Besides, the amount of typing necessary is almost *never* an metric for good design.

Comment: If he is worried about the amount of typing necessary, he picked one of the worst possible languages to do this in.

Comment: @Douglas I'll switch to c# if I find the time :)

Comment: @DouglasBarbin, A property in VB.NET is actually just generating a getter and a setter method for you behind the scenes.  In the MSIL, it's actually very similar to Java, in that way.  MSIL does not inherently support properties.  Properties are a VB language construct which gets interpreted as to methods, so in the end, it's basically the same thing, it's just you end up with another, somewhat unnecessary getter.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin Excelent point about typing.  That made me LOL.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I know  :)  Java just forces you to write the "boilerplate" code yourself.  For what it's worth, properties aren't particularly a VB construct; C# has them as well.  In C#, they look just like a member variable except you can define the getter/setter.

Comment: @StevenDoggart You're right, it's the same numbe rof lines. Anyway, I think accessing it directly is more straightforward. No need to create these "hidden-props"...

Comment: For what it's worth, if you'll be doing it a lot, and the amount of typing is a concern, you could make a simple code snippet for Visual Studio, so when you type `hiddenprop` in your code and press the tab key, it automatically inserts all the code for you.  Lazy programmers unite!

Comment: Ok, so it's generally not recommended to alter internal variables directly but I don't see the problem here.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Just like Douglas said...It's a hacked-together solution...I'll stick with mine :)

Comment: Well, if you make it a `Friend`, it's not really internal anymore, is it? :)  Accessing fields directly is typically since the class then has no control over their value, which is discouraged in classical OOP maxims.  It's also typically discouraged since if you ever did need to make it a property, it would change the signature, thereby breaking compatibility with other assemblies, but since it's a `Friend`, that's not really a concern in this situation.  So yes, it's purely philosophical.  The third issue, which to me is the larger one, will be described in my next comment because no room.

Comment: *MSIL does not inherently support properties.* That's not true. The MSIL/CIL is totally aware of properties and they are declared using the `.property` directive.

Comment: The third issue is that it's unexpected and is therefore confusing.  It's always best to write your code in an "expected" way, because that makes it much easier for other people to read and understand your code.  When you make a property read-only, it is assumed that it is actually read-only--that it's value can only be modified by the class itself.  Therefore, you'd *expect* to see some kind of method somewhere in the class that actually sets the internal variable.  Anything short of that will cause at least some amount of confusion.

Comment: @DominicKexel, Thanks for the clarification, picky as it may be :)  I always enjoy learning something new.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I understand your third issue even if I'm the only developer in my company. And a little confusion is always funny :) So from a stricct OOP-view, I'll stick with friend setter-methods. Or simply set the internal variables in the constructor.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Yeah, picky :-) Because otherwise, I totally agree with you here.